# How to use Hölder's inequality to show $L_q$ is a subspace of $L_p$?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose the measure of $X$ is finite. I  want to show that $L_q(X)$ is a subspace of $L_p(X)$, where $1\le p\le q\le\infty$.

I know I need to use Hölder's inequality, but I am not sure how do I use it.

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this problem really needs Holder's inequality. When $|f(x)|\ge 1$ (if ever), $|f(x)|^q\ge |f(x)|^p$, hence $\displaystyle\int_X |f|^p\,d\mu\le \int_{\{x:|f(x)|\ge1\}} |f|^q\,d\mu+\int_{\{x:|f(x)|<1\}} |f|^p\,d\mu\le \int_X |f|^q\,d\mu+\mu(X)<\infty$, hence $f\in L^p(X)$.

Comment: could you pls explan why |f| >=1?

Comment: @user132177 What do you mean? I didn't say $|f|\ge 1$. I edited the post, hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: what if |f|<1??

Comment: @user132177 I didn't make any suppositions on the value of $f$... $|f|$ can take on whatever values you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $f\in L^{q}(X)$ and show that $\frac{q}{p}$ and $\frac{p-q}{p}$ are Hölder conjugates. Then use the Hölder inequality for the functions $|f|^{p}$ and $1_{X}$. Conclude that $f\in L^{p}(X)$.

Can you see where we needed the assumption $\mu(X)<\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that you can always write

$$f = f \cdot 1_X$$

where $1_X$ is the function which always returns $1$. Now since $X$ has finite measure....

Comment: I am not sure how do I find the measure of X in this problem

Comment: The measure of $X$ is just $\mu(X) = \int_X d\mu$, @user132177.

Comment: ||f||lp = integral(|f|^p)=integral(|f*1|^p<=||f||lq * m(e)^1/r where 1/p=1/q+1/r. is that what I want to show?